# JMeter - IP Source (aka IP Spoofing) option for FTP sampler

Tags: ftp, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, spoofing

I'm trying to achieve FTP session to the server using different client IP address via JMeter. However IP source (aka IP Spoofing) option is only available with HTTP sampler.

BTW, I don't want to use the distributed test (master/salve). i want to simulate the same behavior whats being used by HTTP sampler.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box JMeter doesn't provide possibility set IP address to bind to so you have to do some scripting - change all FTP Samplers to [JSR223 Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

1. Download [groovy-all.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all) form Maven Central and drop it to the /lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter (if it's running) to pick the jar up
3. Replace FTP Samplers with JSR223 Samplers (make sure that "groovy" is selected in the "Language" dropdown
4. Instantiate [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) as follows:

   ```
   FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
   client.setPassiveLocalIPAddress("YOUR IP ADDRESS HERE");
   //FTP specific code here
   ```

References:

- [FTPClientExample.java](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java) - example usage of FTPClient
- [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) - detailed instructions on how to install "groovy" language support into JSR223 test elements, scripting best practices and different scripting engines benchmark.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I'll give a try.

But is there a way to write a script for ip source itself...since I'll be using this for other samplers like Mail, Db etc..

Basically I want to define the ip source as variable and will be defining the client ip's in csv file and the same will be used via csv config element.

We are planning to run a major project using jmeter. Any help is highly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: For the moment it is not possible, you can raise an improvement request in JMeter Bugzilla

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In real world FTP servers will be hit by multiple client IP's not just by 1 client.